# Command not found error in snakemake pipeline despite the package existing in the conda environment

Tags: snakemake

I am getting the following error in the snakemake pipeline:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 16
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       long_read_assembly
        1

[Wed Jan 15 11:35:18 2020]
rule long_read_assembly:
    input: long_reads/F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A_long.fastq.gz
    output: canu-outputs/F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A.subreads.contigs.fasta
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sample=F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A

/usr/bin/bash: canu: command not found
[Wed Jan 15 11:35:18 2020]
Error in rule long_read_assembly:
    jobid: 0
    output: canu-outputs/F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A.subreads.contigs.fasta
    shell:
        canu -p F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A -d canu-outputs genomeSize=8m -pacbio-raw long_reads/F19FTSEUHT1027.PSU4_ISF1A_long.fastq.gz
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

I assume it is meaning that the command canu can not be found. But the Canu package does exist inside the conda environment:

```
(hybrid_assembly) [lamma@fe1 Assembly]$ conda list | grep canu
canu                      1.9                  he1b5a44_0    bioconda
```

The snakefile looks like this:

```
workdir: config["path_to_files"]
wildcard_constraints:
    separator = config["separator"],
    sample = '|' .join(config["samples"]),

rule all:
    input:
        expand("assembly-stats/{sample}_stats.txt", sample = config["samples"])

rule short_reads_QC:
    input:
        f"short_reads/{{sample}}_short{config['separator']}*.fq.gz"

    output:
        "fastQC-reports/{sample}.html"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        """
        mkdir fastqc-reports
        fastqc -o fastqc-reports {input}
        """

rule quallity_trimming:
    input:
        forward = f"short_reads/{{sample}}_short{config['separator']}1.fq.gz",
        reverse = f"short_reads/{{sample}}_short{config['separator']}2.fq.gz",

    output:
        forward = "cleaned_short-reads/{sample}_short_1-clean.fastq",
        reverse = "cleaned_short-reads/{sample}_short_2-clean.fastq"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "bbduk.sh -Xmx1g in1={input.forward} in2={input.reverse} out1={output.forward} out2={output.reverse}  qtrim=rl trimq=10"

rule long_read_assembly:
    input:
        "long_reads/{sample}_long.fastq.gz"

    output:
        "canu-outputs/{sample}.subreads.contigs.fasta"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "canu -p {wildcards.sample} -d canu-outputs genomeSize=8m -pacbio-raw {input}"
rule short_read_alignment:
    input:
        short_read_fwd = "cleaned_short-reads/{sample}_short_1-clean.fastq",
        short_read_rvs = "cleaned_short-reads/{sample}_short_2-clean.fastq",
        reference = "canu-outputs/{sample}.subreads.contigs.fasta"

    output:
        "bwa-output/{sample}_short.bam"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "bwa mem {input.reference} {input.short_read_fwd} {input.short_read_rvs} |  samtools view -S -b > {output}"


rule indexing_and_sorting:
    input:
        "bwa-output/{sample}_short.bam"
    output:
        "bwa-output/{sample}_short_sorted.bam"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "samtools sort {input} > {output}"

rule polishing:
    input:
        bam_files = "bwa-output/{sample}_short_sorted.bam",
        long_assembly = "canu-outputs/{sample}.subreads.contigs.fasta"

    output:
        "pilon-output/{sample}-improved.fasta"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "pilon --genome {input.long_assembly} --frags {input.bam_files} --output {output} --outdir pilon-output"

rule assembly_stats:
    input:
        "pilon-output/{sample}-improved.fasta"
    output:
        "assembly-stats/{sample}_stats.txt"

    conda:
        "/home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml"

    shell:
        "stats.sh in={input} gc=assembly-stats/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_gc.csv gchist=assembly-stats/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_gchist.csv shist=assembly-stats/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_shist.csv > assembly-stats/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_stats.txt"
```

The rule calling canu has the correct syntax as far as I am awear so I am not sure what is causing this error.

Edit:
Adding the snakemake command

```
snakemake --latency-wait 60 --rerun-incomplete --keep-going --jobs 99 --cluster-status 'python /home/lamma/faststorage/scripts/slurm-status.py' --cluster 'sbatch  -t {cluster.time} --mem={cluster.mem} --cpus-per-task={cluster.c} --error={cluster.error}  --job-name={cluster.name} --output={cluster.output} --wait --parsable' --cluster-config bacterial-hybrid-assembly-config.json --configfile yaml-config-files/test_experiment3.yaml --snakefile bacterial-hybrid-assembly.smk
```

Comment: does the "hybrid-assembly" environment (rather than the env that your shell runs) contain "canu"?

Comment: The environment `hybrid_assembly` does contrain canu as shown:

`(hybrid_assembly) [lamma@fe1 Assembly]$ conda list | grep canu
canu                      1.9                  he1b5a44_0    bioconda`

However you quote "hybrid-assembly", Do I have a typo somewhere using - instead of _ ?

Comment: Is that the same result as  "cat /home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml | grep canu" ?

Comment: I appears so yes: `cat /home/lamma/env-export/hybrid_assembly.yaml | grep canu
  - canu=1.9=he1b5a44_0` is the result

Comment: what command are you using to call snakemake?

Comment: I have edited the command into the question :) sorry for delayed reply

Comment: I think you should be using `snakemake ... blah blah blah ... --use-conda` if you want to make your hybrid-assembly environment to be activated for the relevant rules https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#combining-conda-package-management-with-containers

Comment: Oh boy I am dumb, I didn't realise it did not have that in ! Thank for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a snakemake workflow, if certain rules are to be ran within a rule-specific conda environment, the command line call should be of the form

```
snakemake [... various options ...] --use-conda [--conda-prefix <some-directory>]
```

If you don't tell snakemake to use conda, all the `conda: <some_path>` entries in your rules are ignored, and the rules are run in whatever environment is currently activated.

The `--conda-prefix <dir>` is optional, but tells snakemake where to find the installed environment (if you don't specify this, a conda env will be installed within the `.snakemake` folder, meaning that the .snakemake folder can get pretty huge and that the .snakemake folders for multiple projects may contain a lot of duplicated conda stuff)